# JSON Object Query SQL Server

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server, open-json

I have a JSON string which is the following:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 103001058774,
        "name": "status",
        "label": "Status",
        "description": "Ticket status",
        "choices": {
            "2": [
                "Open",
                "Open"
            ],
            "3": [
                "Pending",
                "Pending"
            ],
            "4": [
                "Resolved",
                "Resolved"
            ],
            "5": [
                "Closed",
                "Closed"
            ],
            "6": [
                "Waiting on Customer",
                "Awaiting your Reply"
            ],
            "7": [
                "Waiting on Third Party",
                "Being Processed"
            ],
            "8": [
                "Assigned",
                "Assigned"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I am trying to put this into a SQL table looking like the following from the **CHOICES** leg of the JSON:

| id | agent_label | customer_label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Open | Open |
| 3 | Pending | Pending |
| 4 | Resolved | Resolved |
| 5 | Closed | Closed |
| 6 | Waiting on Customer | Awaiting your Reply |
| 7 | Waiting on Third Party | Being Processed |
| 8 | Assigned | Assigned |

I already have this as a Query and I am on the right lines... But I don't know how to strip out the ID numbers!:

```
DECLARE @jsonStatusesData NVARCHAR (MAX) = *'My JSON String'*

SELECT id = JSON_QUERY(j.value, $.choices')
FROM OPENJSON(@jsonStatusesData) AS j
```

I do have a few more lines in there I need to add in, but ultimately the table above is what I want to do. Of course, that SQL query is just returning the whole Choices branch and doesn't help me at all.

Any help would be great! :)

Thanks,

Ash

Comment: Hope this takes you further along:
```declare @choices varchar(max)  

SELECT @choices = JSON_QUERY(j.value, '$.choices') FROM OPENJSON(@jsonStatusesData) AS j  

SELECT a.[key], a.[value] FROM OPENJSON(@choices) as a```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a second level of `OPENJSON` to break out the `choices` array. And you need to read that array using the `AS JSON` syntax

```sql
SELECT
  j1.id,
  j2.[key],
  agent_label = JSON_VALUE(j2.value, '$[0]'),
  customer_label = JSON_VALUE(j2.value, '$[1]')
FROM OPENJSON(@jsonStatusesData)
  WITH (
    id bigint,
    choices nvarchar(max) AS JSON
  ) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.choices) j2;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/d2-bvAYC)

Answer (score 1):

This does the job for your sample data:

```
select [key] as id, 
    json_value(value, '$[0]') as agent_label, 
    json_value(value, '$[1]') as customer_label
from openjson(@jsonStatusesData, '$[0].choices') AS j
```

Assumptions:

- your json string is an array, with a single object at the top level (in other words, there is only one array of `choices` to unnest)
- in the `choices` array, each object is an array of two scalar values that you want to put side by side

| id | agent_label | customer_label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Open | Open |
| 3 | Pending | Pending |
| 4 | Resolved | Resolved |
| 5 | Closed | Closed |
| 6 | Waiting on Customer | Awaiting your Reply |
| 7 | Waiting on Third Party | Being Processed |
| 8 | Assigned | Assigned |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eWi_qBB8)

Comment: `openjson(@jsonStatusesData, '$[0].choices')` seems simpler. Note that this doesn't work if the outer array has multiple values.

Comment: @Charlieface: yes, thanks for the shorcut in `openjson`. And yes, this supposes only one object at the top level.